# How to send URL params with $resource requests in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular. I have a simple back end API in Laravel which I am trying to consume using AngularJS. Now all the routes in my API can only be accessed if authenticated ie using an auth_token. I need to send a URL parameter with all the $resource requests using my Angular application. How do I accomplish that?

My services.js file looks like:

```
angular.module('airlineServices', ['ngResource'])
    .factory('Airport', function($resource){
        return $resource("http://angulairapi.rohanchhabra.in/airports/:airportCode", {}, {
            query: { method: "GET", isArray: false }
        });
    })
    .factory('Flight', function($resource){
        return $resource("http://angulairapi.rohanchhabra.in/flights");
    })
    .factory('Reservation', function($resource){
        return $resource("http://angulairapi.rohanchhabra.in/reservations/:id");
    });
```

What modifications do I make so that all the factories send a url parameter 'auth_token' with each request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching for a while, I found out how myself.

The resource takes 4 arguments like so:

```
$resource(url, [paramDefaults], [actions], options);
```

Any URL parameter which needs to be passed can be passed using the second argument. It can also be a callback function.